# How to convert my query to Criteria in grails

Tags: grails, criteria

```
class FaciltyUserRole{
    User user
    Role permission
    Facility facility
}

class Facility{
    String id
    String groupName
}
```

These are my domains. I would like to make a query and fetch the facilities with a given user, permission, and the groupName. How can I do that? I have already started my criteria with this, I just have no idea how to filter the facilities I get based on the groupName.

```
def query = {
    and{
        eq("user", user)
        eq("role", permission)

    }
    projections { 
        property("facility") 

    }
}

def facList = FacilityUserRole.createCriteria().list(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

if my understanding is correct this is what you are looking for

```
def query = {
  and{
    eq("user", user)
    eq("role", permission)
    facility{
      eg("groupName", groupName)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: but what if groupName is just a keyword..I intend to implement this in  an autocomplete function...'${groupName%}' Can I use 'like'?

Comment: Yes.. you can use 'like'.. please go through http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html to know more.

Comment: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#criteria to know more about Criteria..

Comment: I have already done that. What I got is an error message:

Unknown column 'facility_a1_.group_name' in 'where clause'. Stacktrace follows:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'facility_a1_.group_name' in 'where clause'

Comment: It should have worked.. Whats the column name(in db) for groupName? Is it not "group_name"?